# How to read identify the indexes of pairs of numbers from a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data.frame:

```
t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
7    15   30   37    4   11   30   37
4    31   44   30   37  39    44   18
3    49   39   34   44   43   26   24
4    31   26   33   12   47   37   15
3    27   34   23   30   30   37    4
9    46   39   34    8   43   26   24
```

For each row, I would like to identify specific (eg. read into by user) sequences of numbers in column `t1 to t8 .`

A sequence consists of numbers that follow each other in a chronological order (time is defined by `t1...t8)`

Example of sequences:

`30, 37` happening at `[t3, t4]` as well `[t7, t8]`

As you see from the above example  I want the index of the start and end columns (eg time t1...t8) and the number of times this occurs.

Desire input:

```
Please specify your sequence: 30 37
```

Desired output:

```
'The timing of 30 37 is: 

     [t3] to [t4] 
     [t7] to [t8] 
     [t4] to [t5]
```

My question is how to write a function that identify the indexes of a specific sequences. Any help is welcomed, please

Below the code that I want to improve:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  u <- u[sapply(u, function(u) any(diff(which(x == u)) > 1))]
  lapply(setNames(u, u), function(u){ 
      ind <- which(x == u)
      lapply(seq(length(ind) - 1), 
             function(i) x[seq(ind[i] + 1, ind[i + 1] - 1)])
  })
})
```

Comment: I am not exactly clear what is your input and expected output. Can you explain?

Comment: @RonakShah many thanks for your time. Basically i would like to read into 2 numbers (like 30 and 37). If these 2 number follow each other in a chronological order (e.g. in the first row 30 37 follow each other in t4 and t5) I would like to receive the index of the numbers (eg. for 30 37 index will be t4 t5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one function which can be helpful. For every row, we paste every element with it's next element and check if it matches with the numbers passed. The function returns a dataframe with row number and column names where a match is found.

```
return_match <- function(df, x, y) {
   #Paste the numbers to match
   concat_str <- paste(x, y, sep = "-")
   #For every row in dataframe
   do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) {
       #Subset the row
       x <- df[i, ]
       #Paste every value with it's next value and compare it with concat_str
       inds = paste(x[-length(x)], x[-1L], sep = "-") == concat_str
       if(any(inds)) {
         #Get the column numbers to match
         row <- which(inds)
         #subset the column name and add row number
         transform(as.data.frame(t(sapply(row, function(y) 
                   names(df)[c(y, y + 1)]))), row = i)
       }
    }))
}


return_match(df, 30, 37)
#  V1 V2 row
#1 t3 t4   1
#2 t7 t8   1
#3 t4 t5   2
#4 t6 t7   5


return_match(df, 39, 34)
#  V1 V2 row
#1 t3 t4   3
#2 t3 t4   6
```

Comment: thank you i like your last line of codes, many thanks I learned from you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with plyr package and without do.call:

```
library(plyr)

obs = read.table(text=
  "t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
  7    15   30   37    4   11   30   37
  4    31   44   30   37  39    44   18
  3    49   39   34   44   43   26   24
  4    31   26   33   12   47   37   15
  3    27   34   23   30   30   37    4
  9    46   39   34    8   43   26   24",
  header=TRUE)

# Find target in one row
f = function(v, target) {
  n = length(v)
  m = length(target)
  res = {}
  for (i in 1:(n-m+1)) {
    if (all(target==v[i:(i+m-1)])) res = c(res,i)
  }
  data.frame(From=res, To=res+m-1)
}

# Find target in all rows
find_matches = function(df, target) {
  df$Row = 1:nrow(df)
  M = adply(df, 1, f, target=target)
  M[, (ncol(M)-2):ncol(M)]
}

# Test
find_matches(obs, c(30,37))
#  Row From To
#1   1    3  4
#2   1    7  8
#3   2    4  5
#4   5    6  7
```